# JPA + Hibernate currentTimestamp() did not match expected type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin, criteria

I have the following code that throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.function.CurrentTimestampFunction@30cb223b] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]`

```
@Transactional
open fun delete(entity: E) {
    val cb = em.criteriaBuilder

    // create update query
    val query = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Entity::class.java)
    val updateEntity = query.from(Entity::class.java)

    // set update and where clause
    query.set("deletedOn", cb.currentTimestamp()) // <- problem exhibited due to this line
    query.where(cb.equal(updateEntity.get<Long>("id"), entity.id))

    // perform update
    em.createQuery(query).executeUpdate()
}
```

The error is due to when I use CriteriaBuilder's `currentTimestamp()`. In Hibernate's `QueryParameterBindingValidator` in `validate(Type paramType, Object bind, TemporalType temporalType)` there's this line

```
final Class parameterType = paramType.getReturnedClass();
```

The entity's `deletedOn` is of type `Timestamp`. `paramType` refers to that field and is of type `TimestampType` (coming from Hibernate). When `getReturnedClass()` is called, it returns `java.util.Date` (I guess because that's the base type?). Unfortunately then the type mismatch occurs with the expression `cb.currentTimestamp()` and the error is thrown.

I could not find a working example online of how to use `currentTimestamp()` from CriteriaBuilder to achieve this task.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that using this line will make it work.

```
query.set(updateEntity.get<Timestamp>("deletedOn"), cb.currentTimestamp())
```

Comment: The correct diamond syntax is `updateEntity.<Timestamp>get("deletedOn")`